# How to use join instead of subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables:

- `Department` (Deptid primary key), Deptname)
- `Employee` (Empid(primary key), Depid(foreign key refer to Deptid), Empname)
- `Salary` (months, Eid(foreign key refer to Empid), slry)

I have a sub query:

```
select Eid, sum(slry) as salarysum 
from Salary 
where Eid in (select Empid from Employee where Depid = 1) 
group by Eid
```

I need to use join instead of this subquery, but I don't know how to use in this context?

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Comment: First try to serach in Google how to join two tables in Sql Server.SO is not a Toutorial site dont post such questions read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in Help center befor asking

Answer (score 1):

Since `Empid` is the primary key for `Employee` table, you can join `Salary` with `Employee` table without worrying about duplicating `Salary` rows.

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT Eid,sum(slry) as salarysum
FROM Salary S
inner join Employee E on E.Empid = S.Eid 
WHERE Depid=1
group by Eid
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below query helps:

```
SELECT 
    Eid,sum(slry)as salarysum 
FROM Salary 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Empid = Eid and Depid=1
GROUP BY Eid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Make a `JOIN on e.Empid = s.Eid`

```
select s.Eid, sum(slry) as salarysum
from Salary s
inner join Employee e on e.Empid = s.Eid
where Depid = 1
group by s.Eid
```